# Инициализация поля класса указателем С++

Tags: c++

Как можно организовать передачу указателя в поле класса так, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было его использовать для модификации переданного объекта вне зависимости от его типа? Объектом могут быть и базовые типы и структуры, любые данные.

**Не используя шаблоны. Интересует в принципе существует ли механизм.**

Можно ли организовать такое в случае **только** базовых типов? Важно сохранить примитивный вид инициализации класса.

```
Class_name(const Some_random_type* Obj_or_type);
```

Поправка: при инициализации нельзя конвертировать тип передаваемого объекта/аргумента, т.е нельзя делать сlass_name((void*)Obj_or_type); Т.е вызов как есть вся логика работы как с типом указателя так и самим объектом внутри определения класса.

Comment: Ну передавайте `void*`, а там уж приводите к нужному типу...

Comment: Ну указатель как void * можно передать, но чтобы с ним работать надо знать его настоящий тип.

Comment: нужно было добавить что в при инициализации нельзя конвертировать тип передаваемого объекта/аргумента.Т.е нельзя делать сlass_name((void*)Obj_or_type); Т.е вызов как есть вся логика работы как с указателем так и самим объектом внутри определения класса.

Comment: Унаследовать объект от абстрактного класса, в котором прописать все методы.

Comment: Почему не хотите использовать шаблоны? Нет, конечно можно перегрузить конструктор для кучи встроенных типов, но зачем?

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. О какой "модификации переданного объекта" может идти речь, если его тип не известен совершенно? Приведите пример такой модификации.